# Find Max of Multiple Lists

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm pretty new to java streams and am trying to determine how to find the max from each list, in a list of lists, and end with a single list that contains the max from each sublist.

I can accomplish this by using a `for` loop and `stream` like so:

```
// databaseRecordsLists is a List<List<DatabaseRecord>>

List<DatabaseRecord> mostRecentRecords = new ArrayList<>();

for (List<DatabaseRecord> databaseRecords : databaseRecordsLists) {
            mostRecentRecords.add(databaseRecords.stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparing(DatabaseRecord::getTimestamp))
                    .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new));
        }
```

I've looked into the `flatMap` api, but then I'll only end up with a single map of all `DatabaseRecord` objects, where I need a max from each individual list.

Any ideas on a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the expected result? Do you want to extract the whole sub-list where the max record is located in.. or records from each list that have the max timestamp... or just that one particular one that results in `mostRecentRecords` with one item?

Comment: edited to hopefully make more clear: end with a single list that contains the max from each sublist

Comment: Do you really want to throw `NoSuchElementException`? If the collection is empty and no max timestamp is found, then the rest of the records will be ignored and no result returned. I suggest filtering them out (up to you).

Comment: Btw. include "end with a single list that contains the max from each sublist" sentence to you question.

Comment: good suggestions. updated the question further and will use filtering. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `flatMap`. Create a `Stream<List<DatabaseRecord>>`, and map each `List<DatabaseRecord>` of the `Stream` to the max element. Then collect all the max elements into the output `List`.

```
List<DatabaseRecord> mostRecentRecords =
    databaseRecordsLists.stream()
                        .map(list -> list.stream()
                                         .max(Comparator.comparing(DatabaseRecord::getTimestamp))
                                         .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Care to add some explanation?

Comment: that's great. thank you! have been trying to figure this out for hours!

Comment: `list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(DatabaseRecord::getTimestamp)).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new)` is the verbose alternative to the good old single call to `Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparing(DatabaseRecord::getTimestamp))`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, I suggested to rather ignore the empty collection, otherwise, no result would be returned and `NoSuchElementException` thrown even the empty collection *might* (?) be a valid state. If so, you can improve the current solution:

```
databaseRecordsLists.stream()
    .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())                              // Only non-empty ones
    .map(list -> list.stream()     
         .max(Comparator.comparing(DatabaseRecord::getTimestamp)) // Get these with max
         .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new))               // Never happens
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                                // To List
```

If you use a version higher than Java 8:

- As of Java 10, `orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new)` can be subsituted with [`orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()).
- As of Java 11, you can use [`Predicate.not(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)), therefore the filter part would look like: `.filter(Predicate.not(List::isEmpty))`.

Comment: `Predicate.not(…)` requires Java 11. Besides that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248748/find-max-of-multiple-lists#comment108357366_61248804

Comment: Thanks, I edit the Java 8 compatibility. Your way of comparison looks much better than mine (I still tend to think "in Streams" mostly). You might want to post it as an answer? I don't want to copy.

Comment: is there a benefit to filtering in this way rather over `.filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)`?

Comment: The List is not wrapped in Optional, so you cannot do this.